# Syntax Error: invalid syntax as to 'OPTIONS' (Django context)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

When I input `python3 manage.py runserver`, the terminal displays the following:

```
      File "/home/ms/myproject/myproject/settings.py", line 60
    'OPTIONS':{
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you help me with this Traceback?

My templates in the file settings.py look this way:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS':True
    'OPTIONS':{
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Comment: You missed comma after `'APP_DIRS':True`. It should be `'APP_DIRS':True,`.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a Comma after `'APP_DIRS':True`